# C# every row send e-mail to rows recipient

Tags: c#, email, datagridview, cell, rows

how to send every cells value from the datagridview rows ?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e9Ls.png)

Example:
vasia@mail.ru recipient get: 
Vasia owed 100 EUR.
liuda@mailru
Liuda owed 23 EUR.

my code sent to multi user:

```
 private void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Debt", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Email",typeof(string)) });

        dt.Rows.Add("Vasia", "130", "vasia@mail.com");
        dt.Rows.Add("Liuda", "23", "liuda@test.com");
        dt.Rows.Add("Grisa", "2560", "grisa@test.com");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;


        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string emailId = dt.Rows[i]["email"].ToString();
            SendEmailUsingGmail(emailId);
        }

        //write code to send mail

    }
    private void SendEmailUsingGmail(string toEmailAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.xx");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxa@xxxx.ru");
            mail.To.Add(toEmailAddress);
            mail.Subject = "tgggggg ";
            mail.Body = "Aš,  papildžiau planą šiais produktais:  PRAŠAU PATIKRINKITE PLANĄ !!!";

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx@xxx.ru", "xxxxx");
            //SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Informavimo laiškas išsiųstas Tiekimo skyriui bei Gamybai");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

how to send in BODY every cells value from the datagridview rows to each email ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the email body string then loop through the emails. I changed your code slightly to do this:

```
        private void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Debt", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Email",typeof(string)) });

            dt.Rows.Add("Vasia", "130", "vasia@mail.com");
            dt.Rows.Add("Liuda", "23", "liuda@test.com");
            dt.Rows.Add("Grisa", "2560", "grisa@test.com");
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;

            string bodyText = BuildStringFromDT(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string emailId = row["Email"].ToString();
                SendEmailUsingGmail(emailId, bodyText);
            }

            //write code to send mail

        }
        private string BuildStringFromDT(DataTable dt)
        {
            List<string> final = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                List<string> temp = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    temp.Add(row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
                }
                final.Add(string.Join("\t", temp));
            }
            return string.Join("\r\n", final);
        }
        private void SendEmailUsingGmail(string toEmailAddress, string bodyText)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.xx");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxa@xxxx.ru");
                mail.To.Add(toEmailAddress);
                mail.Subject = "tgggggg ";
                mail.Body = bodyText;

                SmtpServer.Port = 25;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx@xxx.ru", "xxxxx");
                //SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Informavimo laiškas išsiųstas Tiekimo skyriui bei Gamybai");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a plain text `Body` property in the code I'd recommend composing an HTML based message body where you can place tables correctly.

In case you are using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`, you can use:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Note the `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` is obsolete, but if using it:

```
mail.BodyFormat
```